# What is the dot product of two randomly generated 0-mean unit-vectors?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Given pairs of random 0-mean unit vectors, what kind of distribution is generated by their dot products?

Judging from a number of results I've generated myself, the distributions appear to be somewhat gaussian...

Comment: For large dimension $n$, if the components are independent identically distributed with reasonable distribution, one would expect somewhat Gaussian because of the Central Limit Theorem. For smallish $n$, one would have to compute with specified distributions.